# How do java loop conditions work?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am using this **for** loop:

```
ArrayList<String> buttonTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i == 3; i++) {
    out.println("Looping!");
    buttonTitles.add(String.format("Button %d", i)); 
}
```

However, the code inside the loop is never executed. What is wrong with my statement?

**Update:** thanks for all answers, it seems that shifting to a new language could make you miss some basics! :)

Comment: Writing 'i == 3' means "loop while i is 3" not "loop until i is 3"

Comment: Your loop is like writing `int i = 0; while(i == 3) { /* do something */ i++; }`  If `i = 0` then `i == 3` must be false and the loop will not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop only continues while the condition is true. In your case the condition is `i == 3` which is never true since your loop doesn't continue far enough to get to that.

I'm guessing you want this:

```
ArrayList<String> buttonTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    out.println("Looping!");
    buttonTitles.add(String.format("Button %d", i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Loops from 0 to 2 (inclusive)
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) // Loops from 0 to 3 (inclusive)
```

Your original loop wil never work because initially `i` is equal to `0`. Your second condition in your for loop states that `i` must equal `3`, which never gets there.

The for loop continues while the second condition always remains true (which isn't from when `i` starts at `0`).

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the for loop is the condition.  Basically say do this while the condition still holds true.  Since i is initialized to 0, i == 3 is never true.  i < 3 is presumably the correct condition.